# Deep updates are not supported in PUT operations

Tags: c#, ajax, wcf-data-services

Why .Net DataServices (Astoria) doesn't support deep updates, but enable deep inserts?
How to update object graph through AJAX?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc907912.aspx

Answer (score 1):

The only reason for doing updates together is performance and update all or nothing scenarios, both of which are achieved by batching all the updates as one request.

Is there a reason why you cannot use batch to update the object graph?

Thanks
Pratik

Answer (score 0):

See [this answer](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1c8f2995-f8a9-4488-83d9-218681be0dc2/deep-updates-are-not-supported-in-put-merge-or-patch-operations) by Vitek Karas on MSDN.

Copy: *(the questions he refers to are questions one would ask to understand why deep updates are complex with regard to the semantics their syntax must carry)*

> Some of the questions:
>
> - If the inner feed only contains one item, did the client wanted that item to be added only, or did it mean to also remove all the other items from the navigation?
> - If the inner feed contains an item which is already present in the collection, it probably means to update it, but what about the other items in the collection. Should they be removed?
> - If the answer to the top two questions above is to "not remove", how do I remove an item from the collection using the "deep update" method then?
> - If there's a way using the "deep update" to remove an item from the collection, does it mean to just remove the item from the navigation, or also delete the item completely?
>
> You could use batch to submit multiple requests as one to overcome this.